# Best way to deal with non-continuously differentiable error functions in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, gradient-descent, mse, derivative

Suppose you have the following set of $n=9$ numbers x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] and the corresponding y values [10, 2.5, 1.1, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0.15, 0.12] which visualized look like this:

[image]

I'd like to fit a function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\theta x^2}$ to the points making use of a mean squared error loss function to find an optimal value for $\theta$. The loss function would be defined as $J(\theta)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{\theta x_i^2}-y_i)^2$
and the derivative of $J$ with respect to $\theta$ would be $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} J(\theta)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2(\theta x^2y-1)}{\theta^3x^4}$.

The problem I'm now facing is that as the function is obviously undefined at $a=0, \theta=0$, the convergence towards the minimum of the cost function (which would be around $\theta=0.1$) will fail when $\theta$ is initialized with a negative value. Visualizing the cost function for the first point $x=1, y=10$ clearly shows that when $\theta=-1$ the slope at this point is positive which will cause $\theta$ to become smaller and smaller using the update rule $\theta_{new} = \theta - \alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} J(\theta)$ when in fact, $\theta$ should converge towards $0.1$.

[image]

My question is: What is the correct way to deal with this situation? In all the textbook examples I've seen, the cost function was always a continuous convex function but what to do when this is not the case?

Comment: Is it correct to say that $\theta$ only takes on values in a specific set, such as positive numbers? If so, you'll need to take care to choose an optimization method and intialization that respects the constraints on $\theta$. But for this specific problem, it's probably sufficient to just initialize $\theta$ to a sensible value and use a small step size.

Comment: That's correct. But what would then be a robust approach to set a reasonable $\theta$ in case I want to try different functions automatically?

Comment: Since $\theta$ is constrained to be positive, you could use unconstrained optimization of $\gamma$ and the identity $\exp(\gamma) = \theta$ because $\exp(\gamma)$ is positive for all real $\gamma$ and $\exp$ is monotonic and differentiable everywhere. But this is just a simplistic solution. There are probably better ones.

Comment: What is "$a$"?  Why are you concerned about differentiability at $\theta=0$?  You *must* have $\theta \gt 0$ for this to make any sense.

Comment: $\alpha$ is the learning rate. Why does $\theta$ have to be > 0? Usually in machine learning algorithms the initial weights are set randomly which can - depending on the initialization function - also include negative values. And even if $\theta$ is positive, the algorithm is not robust because when $\theta$ is converging towards 0.1 and gets just a littler smaller than that, the high slope between 0 and 0.1 will lead to a high update of $\theta$, kicking it out if the optimum quickly.

Comment: @SimonNobel Your account of "most machine learning algorithms" is rather incomplete. The generic gradient descent algorithm outlined here is an **unconstrained** optimization method. But, as you've shown, unconstrained optimization is not a good choice for a problem where there are constraints on the parameter values.